# How to order sqlite table according to accending integer?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I am having some problems with ORDER BY in android sqlite.

I am using this query to reorder my listview :

```
Select * From tbl_name ORDER BY WithOrder asc
```

Where WithOrder is an Integer type column. The expected behavior I was hoping for was that sqlite will reorder the rows as ....8,9,10,11,12.... but it is reordering the list according to the first digit instead as ....10,11,8,9....

Please help me with reordering the table with ascending values of integer...I can not opt for any other column or datatype to reorder as I depend heavily on WithOrder for general calculations when the user reorders the list.

Thanks!

Parvaz Bhaskar

Comment: Is WithOrder String or Number type?

Comment: maybe `WithOrder` is not a integer typed column.

Comment: WithOrder is Integer Type

Comment: may be let me check again

Comment: Ok the column type turned out to be VARCHAR...is this the reason for such sorting?

Comment: me too got the same thing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While numbers are sorted according to their numerical value, strings are sorted lexicographically, beginning with the first character.
In particular, the character `1` is less than the character `8`, so any string beginning with `1` (such as `11`) is sorted before any string beginning with `8`.

Recreate your table so that the `WithOrder` column has type `INTEGER`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Cursor c =  SQLiteDatabase_OBJ.query("Table_name", null, null, null, null, null, "WithOrder ASC");
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

Try this `ORDER BY CAST(WithOrder AS INTEGER) ASC`

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. It will be helpful for future users as well.